# Why does typescript give an error when using a constant for an enum type?

Tags: typescript

When I try to pass a conatant instead of in-place values ​​for the field below, I get a type error, but if I use an in-place value, everything works fine

```
import * as z from "zod";

const data = ["1", "2"];

// this way works fine
/*
  age: z.enum<any, [string, ...string[]]>(["1", "2"])
*/

const schema = z.object({
  name: z.number(),
  age: z.enum<any, [string, ...string[]]>(data) // error here
});
```

**and here is how z.enum type look**

```
declare function createZodEnum<U extends string, T extends Readonly<[U, ...U[]]>>(values: T): ZodEnum<Writeable<T>>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `T extends Readonly<[U, ...U[]]>`, it would require a type like `['foo', 'bar', /* etc */]`, but not `Array<string>`.

In your code,

```js
const data = ["1", "2"];
```

is actually inferred as

```js
const data: Array<string> = ["1", "2"];
```

---

You could either

```js
const data = ["1", "2"] as const;
```

or as the way you've commented out.

---

Note how the [README](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#zod-enums) said

> Alternatively, use as const to define your enum values as a tuple of strings. See the [const assertion docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) for details.

Comment: Yes, I have found already, but anyway thanks!!